# Where does MacOS store the *list* of active keychains?

Tags: osx-mavericks, keychain

My login.keychain does not appear in the keychain search list. I am convinced this is a permissions problem, left over from a recent migration from an older machine, which caused havoc for a time.

I can add the keychain in Keychain Access (KA) and can use it, even adding and deleting items. However, when I quit and re-start KA, it's missing again. I tried using Terminal to add it using "security", but this had the same result. The list simply won't change.

The chain itself seems fine, and I used the Recreate and Keychain First Aid to no avail - I think because they're attacking different issues.

So, does anyone know where this information is stored, and what files I might need to fix/delete to get everything working again?

Comment: I'm not sure why your question is being downvoted – you asked a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keychain search lists are stored in `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.plist` for the system, and `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.plist` for each user.

The plist contents look like this:

```xml
<dict>
    <key>DLDBSearchList</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>DbName</key>
            <string>... path to keychain file ...</string>
            <key>GUID</key>
            <string>{...}</string>
            <key>SubserviceType</key>
            <integer>6</integer>
        </dict>

        ... more dict entries ...

    </array>
    <key>DefaultKeychain</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>DbName</key>
            <string>... path to keychain file ...</string>
            <key>GUID</key>
            <string>{...}</string>
            <key>SubserviceType</key>
            <integer>6</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Comment: Thank you! I suspect the down votes are due to it being more appropriate on one of the other "stack" properties, but I tried that to no avail.

Comment: Oh I should point this out: I had backed up my keychain to a USB stick, and recreated it. I still had problems with it disappearing after that. But then I wanted to move one of my certs back, so I opened the copy on the USB and copied it over. It's been working fine since then! Something about opening that file caused the plist to rest I guess. In any event, new build finally going out!

Comment: Actually, Tach, do you mind checking something for me? I see that my permissions are "everyone, me, everyone", and the first everyone is set to "Custom". I suspect this is the root cause of my problem. What does yours look like?

Comment: Glad you were able to get it working :) My user copy of `com.apple.security.plist` has these permissions – Me: read & write, Staff: read only, Everyone: read only.

Comment: Thank you Tach! So it does indeed appear to be a bogus permission!